# rufus-scheduler concurrency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rufus-scheduler

I'm running a ruby on rails application that needs to perform a certain task every one minute:

```
scheduler.every '1m' do
   .....
end
```

But sometimes, the job takes longer than 1 minute to complete the work. What is happening is that before he finished, Rufus starts a new job, which "kills" the earlier job before it is over.
Is there any way to Rufus expect the job finish before starting the next one?

Ps.: Still in development, so I'm using Webrick

Comment: Hm. I'm not familiar with Rufus, but I've done lots of scheduling. You might look at doing an interval job instead. From Rufus' documentation: `Whereas "every" jobs are like "every 10 minutes, do this", interval jobs are like "do that, then wait for 10 minutes, then do that again, and so on"` Basically, if you schedule one of those, it will wait for that to complete, then schedule again in 1m (or whatever your interval is).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a file lock check for your tasks. There is a gem that makes it really easy: https://github.com/cph/single_file.

Basically, you can wrap your task in a SingleFile block and the first task will put a lock on the temp file. When it schedules to run again, if the previous task still has a lock placed on the file (it's not done running), the task won't run that time.

```
include SingleFile

scheduler.every '1m' do
  with_file_lock("/tmp/magic_is_happening.lock") do
    MagicClass.poof!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Christopher Davies' response in form of a comment is very good. He points to "interval" jobs.

https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#in-at-every-interval-cron

You could thus do

```
scheduler.interval '1m' do
  # ...
end
```

to let rufus-scheduler run your block with 1 minute between each run.

If you dig further down the documentation, there is another technique exposed:

https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#overlap--false

```
scheduler.every '1m', overlap: false do
  # ...
end
```

The scheduler will check every minute. If the block is not yet running, it will run it, if it is running it won't trigger, it will come back a minute later and check again.

Pick the technique that fits your needs.